# Overriding close button action in Eclipse e4

Tags: button, eclipse-rcp, e4, minimize, efxclipse

Instead of closing my Eclipse RCP application when clicking on the close button [X] I'd like the application to be minimized.
In the `ExitAddon` I've tried this:

```java
@Override
public boolean close(MWindow window) {
  window.getTags().add(IPresentationEngine.MINIMIZED);
  return false;
}
```

But it doesn't do the trick.

Is that possible to do and how?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by 'ExitAddon' you mean something implementing `IWindowCloseHandler`.

Setting the shell to minimized directly seems to work:

```java
@Override
public boolean close(final MWindow window)
{
  IEclipseContext context = window.getContext();

  Shell shell = (Shell)context.get(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL);

  shell.setMinimized(true);

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thx Greg, you assume well. I just forgot to say I'm going with javaFX.

Answer (score 0):

With javaFX the solution was:

```java
@Override
public boolean close(MWindow window) {
        IEclipseContext context = window.getContext();
        Stage stage = (Stage)context.get(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL);
        stage.setIconified(true);

      return false;
    }
```